# number to string conversion with padding in awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to convert a number to a string in awk. I would like my string to be left-padded with zeros. E.g., 3 would become "00000003". I have the following test case:

`gawk 'BEGIN { CONVFMT = "%08d"  ; a = 233 ; print ""a }'`

`233`

It prints "233" not "00000233".
Replacing a = 233 with  a = 233.0 doesn't change anything.
However, replacing a = 233 with  a = 233.1 changes everything, and my one-liner correctly prints padded string:

`gawk 'BEGIN { CONVFMT = "%08d"  ; a = 233.1 ; print ""a }'`

`00000233`

What am I missing ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CONVFMT` is not used here. In the gawk manual it says:

> As a special case, if a number is an integer, then the result of
> converting it to a string is always an integer, no matter what the
> value of CONVFMT may be. Given the following code:
>
> ```
>    CONVFMT = "%2.2f"
>    a = 12
>    b = a ""
> ```
>
> b has the value "12", not "12.00".

It wouldn't print 00000233 even if 233.0 was used:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN { CONVFMT = "%08d"  ; a = 233.0 ; print ""a }'
233
```

You should use `sprintf` to achieve what you want:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN { a=233; name=sprintf("%08d",a); print name }'
00000233
```

Comment: Thanks! I should've done my RTFM. Any suggestion of how to achieve this without CONVFMT? In the end I don't want to print the newly generated string (so, printf will not help), I intend to use it as name for a file. The idea being to increment the number and convert to string to generate as many file names as required, with all of them having the same length.

Comment: @ArturP: I suggest `gawk 'BEGIN { a=233; name=sprintf("%08d",a); print name }'`

Comment: @ArturP see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions for more info on `sprintf()`.

Comment: sprintf does exactly what I need. Thanks all!

Comment: @ArturP: I incorporated Cyrus's idea into my answer. If you like this answer please mark it as solved to let other users
know your problem is solved. Also see [What should I
do when someone answers my
question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)